# Restart Server from ASP.NET application when AppPool is ran under LocalSystem or LocalService account

Tags: c#, asp.net, security, iis

Is it possible to restart server from ASP.NET application that is hosted by LocalSystem or LocalService account? This is working when I create custom administrative account and put AppPool to run under that account:

```
Process.Start("shutdown", "/r /d 4:1 /t 10");
```

However, I don't want to have custom accounts (because of password expiry and need to update all AppPools when User passwords are changed - I need to maintain multiple servers).

So, is this possible?

Comment: OK guys... it's possible. Follow @vcsjones recommendation on secpol.msc and be sure to also add "Force shutdown from a remote system" in step 3. Then restart computer in order for policies to load and that's it. I've used LocalService account (LOCAL SERVICE in Select Users or Groups) dialog. And it works with Shutdown.exe (command I've used in question).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can always start the process with a different identity that can restart the server:

```
var info = new ProcessStartInfo("shutdown.exe", "/r /t 0");
info.UserName = "accountWithAdminPermissions";
//A not-so-secure use of SecureString
var secureString = new SecureString();
var password = "abc123";
foreach (var letter in password)
{
    secureString.AppendChar(letter);
}
info.Password = secureString;
var restart = new Process();
restart.StartInfo = info;
restart.Start();
```

---

If you just want to give a non-Administrative account the permission to restart the server:

1. Open `secpol.msc`.
2. Navigate to Local Policies\User Rights Assignment.
3. Find `Shutdown The System`.
4. Add the account.

This might be a good way of using an account for least privilege. That way you don't have to use a really big hammer like an account in the Administrator group.

`Shutdown.exe` (I believe) always requires Administrator permissions. You can refer to [this MSDN post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/csharpgeneral/thread/118ac7b1-c786-4c56-9eb0-24fc96e31548) on restarting the server without shutdown.exe.

Comment: Yeah... then the problem is that I need to maintain passwords in web.config on multiple servers. Although this is probably the best solution with specifying user accounts.

Comment: @kape123 You could just grant your App Pool user rights to restart the system without giving them the the full Administrator role.

Comment: Thanks - I think I have it with that secpol.msc - I'll add SYSTEM to the list of users allowed to Shutdown The System.

Answer (score 2):

You could have your code impersonate a specific account when making that call or stand up a web service with one account.  I recommend the web service, worst case is you update one app pool.  You could also lock down the web service internally to only your applications.

[A small C# Class for impersonating a User](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/zetaimpersonator.aspx)

Comment: Process.Start has overload for impersonating user... and I'm managing multiple servers so that's why I'm locking for a way to do this under LocalSystem/LocalService - I've already isolated Process.Start to WebService. Any other ideas?

Comment: I would think you could do something with Group Policy, not my expertise though.  Server Fault might be a better place for your answer.