# Shutdown or Restart Machine In C# and ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, process, cmd, shutdown

I want to be able to shutdown down or restart the server that my ASP.NET app is running on. The following code works great in debug mode:

```
Process process = new Process();
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
startInfo.FileName = "shutdown";
startInfo.Arguments = "/r /f /t 0";
startInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
startInfo.Verb = "runas";
process.StartInfo = startInfo;
process.Start();
```

I have also tried this code, but I receive the following error "The Process object must have the UseShellExecute property set to false in order to start a process as a user":

```
var info = new ProcessStartInfo("shutdown.exe", "/r /t 0");
        info.UserName = "administrator";
        //A not-so-secure use of SecureString
        var secureString = new SecureString();
        var password = "password";
        foreach (var letter in password)
        {
            secureString.AppendChar(letter);
        }
        info.Password = secureString;
        var restart = new Process();
        restart.StartInfo = info;
        restart.Start();
```

I add the the following to my code:

```
info.UseShellExecute = false;
```

Then the error "The Process object must have the UseShellExecute property set to false in order to start a process as a user" goes away, but the the code executes like the first block of code

The server will restart when I execute the code in debug mode or if I run the command is cmd. However when I run the app live on the server, it will not restart. I don't receive any error, or pops saying that the server is or is not going to restart. Can some tell me please what I am doing wrong?

**UPDATE:** I have added a `try-catch` and the app never throws an exception. However when I looked up the event logs, I have found the application error event 1000 for shutdown.exe

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8283042/64262

Comment: Isn't it reasuring to learn that your ASP code is not running with administrator priviliges?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Restart Server from ASP.NET application when AppPool is ran under LocalSystem or LocalService account](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8282987/restart-server-from-asp-net-application-when-apppool-is-ran-under-localsystem-or)

Comment: @jdv-JandeVaan Indeed it is

Comment: @Habib No it is not a duplicate I have tried the code block in the link that you have post, I still can't reboot the server.

Comment: @nate, specify an admin user for the machine as the process owner

Comment: @Habib is this "info.UserName = "accountWithAdminPermissions";" not the same?

Comment: @andleer I have tried the link that you suggested, but I receive the same results

Comment: @nate, yes, make sure you are using the correct user name and password, also try to put this code in `try-catch` and log the exception, see if you get anything

Comment: @Habib I have used a try-catch no exception is being thrown.

Comment: assuming this is a remote server you are trying to shutdown you can use the shutdown command with /m and set the target computer and /s or /r to shutdown or restart the computer. this way seems easier than the others

Comment: @CS_STEM no the server is not remote that is why I didn't use the m switch

Comment: then if it is local then you can either just use shutdown /s /r if this does not work then you need to recreate the shutdown.exe otherwise the other option is to force shutdown by pressing the power button on the machine itself. if you can't do that, then try creating a batch to kill all processes in task manager mainly rundll 32 explorer.exe and all other processes.

Comment: @CS_STEM can you be a little more descriptive about how to "recreate the shutdown.exe"? I thought that is what I was doing.

Comment: first does shutdown /s /f work on the server? if not then you may have a corrupt file in the system meaning you should figure out what file is corrupt, or use the installation disk (if you have one) and run it in hopes of repairing the file or registry.

Comment: @CS_STEM Yes the code works in debug mode, and if you run the command in cmd

Comment: so basically you are trying to "recreate the wheel" why? if the shut down command works in the system all you should need is a batch to shutdown the server. try the following: in notepad type @echo off shutdown /r or /s /f /t 00 and save it as a .BAT

Answer (score 1):

The account under which your application pool is running does not have sufficient privileges to reboot the system, that's why it doesn't occur.

You can change this by logging on to the server and subsequently going to `Control Panel > Administrative Tools > Local Security Policy`, expanding the `Security Settings > Local Policies > User Rights Assignment` node and going to the `Shut down the system` setting. Add the application pool account (or its parent group if you have a group for it) to that list.

Comment: I am not sure how to find the account this is running under app pool. I assumed it was administrator

Comment: You can view this by going to the IIS Manager, browsing to the folder in which your application resides, and clicking 'Basic settings'. This will show you the name of the application pool. Go to 'Application pools', find the application pool by its name, and look under 'Advanced settings' to find out the account. If it says 'NetworkService' or 'ApplicationPoolIdentity', change it to a dedicated account (don't use your own account!)

Comment: I changed the the identity to the administrator account, and added administrator account in the local security policy. I still can't reboot the server.

Comment: @nate your problem may not be the code after some more research and a hunch that your problem is not due to the code it is most likely a program that is running on the server that is preventing a reboot IE you need to google "unable to reboot Windows server".

Comment: The server is reboot able. I have been able to do this in batch files, and in cmd using the shutdown command.